# get return result after post to server (from iphone)

Tags: iphone

I make iphone application, post parametes to JSP (test.jsp in server) from iphone. The following is my codes:

```
NSData *postData = [@"&test=123&field=456" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
// Init and set fields of the URLRequest
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/test.jsp"]]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (connection) {
// Return data of the request
NSData *receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}

[request release];
```

But my problem is: I can not get return result from JSP server. 
How I can setup in JSP to get return result in iPhone? and in iPhone too?

Thank all

Answer (score 0):

Do you implement this in your delegate:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

Comment: what I have to setup in my JSP server ?

Comment: I don't know anything about JSP, but I would assume some kind of receive message & respond to message is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Data won't just magically appear in your `receivedData` instance. You need to implement the delegate methods for `NSURLConnection`. Take a look at Apple's documentation on how to this all properly.